# Understanding Calabi's conjecture proof: What is it meant by the logarithm of a differential form?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading several books and articles concerning Yau's proof of the Calabi conjecture. I want to have a deep understading of how and why such proof actually works, but most articles are aimed at specialists and give little or no detail to several steps.

For example, in Moroianu's [Lectures on Kähler Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=1139463004) or Besse's [Einstein Manifolds](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=3540152792), one starts with a compact connected Kähler manifold $(X^n, \omega)$, where $\omega\in \mathcal{A}^{1, 1}(X)$ is its Kähler form. Then, if $\nu_g$ is the Riemannian measure associated to $X$, one defines $$\mathcal{K}:= \left\{ \varphi\in \mathcal C^\infty(X, \mathbb R): \omega + dd^c\varphi>0, \int_X \varphi \, \mathrm{d}\nu_g=0\right\}. $$
Here, $\omega + dd^c\varphi>0$ means that $\omega + dd^c\varphi$ is a Kähler form. More generally, an $(1, 1)-$form $\alpha= \mathrm{i}\, \alpha_{jk}dz^j\wedge d\bar{z}^k\in \bigwedge^{1, 1}(V^*)$ is said to be positive if for all $\xi\in\mathbb C^n$ one has
$  \alpha_{jk}\xi^j \bar\xi^k\geq0 $.

After some considerations, one also defines the set
$$\mathcal K':=\left\{ f\in \mathcal C^\infty(X, \mathbb R):  \int_X e^f\cdot \omega^{(n)}= \int_X  \omega^{(n)} \right\},$$
where $\omega^{(n)}$ is the $n$-fold wedge product of $\omega$.
 It turns out that proving Calabi's conjecture is equivalent to proving that the map $\mathrm{Cal}\colon \mathcal{K}\to \mathcal{K}'$ is a diffeomorphism, where $$\mathrm{Cal}(\varphi):=\log\left( \frac{(\omega+dd^c\varphi)^{(n)}}{\omega^{(n)}} \right).$$
Actually this is a quite standard procedure which appears in almost every place dealing with this topic.

Now, the notation bugs me a lot, what is it meant by the quotient $\displaystyle\frac{(\omega+dd^c\varphi)^{(n)}}{\omega^{(n)}}$?, and how does it make sense to take the "logarithm" of such thing?

We also know that $\omega^{(n)}= n! \mathrm{vol}$, where $\mathrm{vol}$ is the volume form of $X$

And please, don't be so harsh on me, I'm still an undergraduate student and I'm actually learning all these things on my own. I want an answer as clear and detailed as possible, no matter if it is a trivial thing after all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $(\omega+dd^c\varphi)^{(n)}$ is an $n$ form and is thus of the form $f\cdot\omega^{(n)}$ for a well defined, smooth function $f$. That would be my guess.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it makes sense in that way. Let's wait for someone to confirm it just to be sure :-)

Comment: Indeed, and since $\varphi \in \mathcal{K}$, the function Olivier calls $f$ will be positive, so $\log f$ is well-defined. (To be precise, $(\omega+dd^c \varphi)^{(n)}$ is a $(n,n)$-form.)